# jQuery: Unbind event handler

Tags: jquery

I chose to go with binding element to the body to have them affecting elements even though they are not yet there. Now, I want to unbind some handlers as I go and this is where I am encountering some difficulties.

Code:

```
$('body').unbind('click', deleteComment); //unbind
$('body').on('click', '.deleteCommentButton > img', deleteComment); //binding
```

The question is how I am supposed to unbind it specifically for `.deleteComment > img`?

Comment: If you use .on you need .off to unbind

Answer (score 3):

If you use .on you need .off to unbind

```
$("body").off('click', '.deleteCommentButton > img', deleteComment);
```

look here http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 2):

You can remove this by using:

```
$("body").off('click', '.deleteCommentButton > img', deleteComment);
```

This will unbind the event handler from the selected elements.

[Link to the api](http://api.jquery.com/off/)